# my own c++ qt library to be used in qtruby, qtpython etc

Tags: c++, qt4, pyqt4, qtruby

I'm starting an institute project. I'll try to create a "web-typograph", a tool that's to be used to correct texts (according to typographic rules of a language) before they're sent to the site. My choice is C++ with Qt because I'd like to create "multilingual" library (I mean it could be used from Ruby, Python, PHP and so on).

Honestly, I heard something about QtRuby, QtPython (even PHP Qt...) but I just can't imagine, how I can bind my library with them.

P.S. Yes, I've googled. But some comments of the experienced would be nice :)

Comment: Why Qt? Nothing you're talking about here sounds like GUI related stuff, and therefore shouldn't really rely on Qt at all.

Comment: Hm, I think that Qt's power is not only in its GUI. I thought about plain C++. But I'd like more transparent way to operate files, strings. Another task is to load data (text/html) from given url. Of course, I could use some separate libraries like curl and google's re2. Is this way better than use some libs of Qt?

Comment: Do you found the answer? I have the same problem and I have googled as well but I have not seen good answer at all.

Comment: @Billy  Qt is much, much more than just a GUI library.  In fact, it provides a wide range of tools that even rival Boost in many areas.  Of course, the added bonus of Qt is a full-featured GUI toolkit that is eminently deployable on most platforms.

Comment: @dusktreader: My main issue with Qt is that it is not a C++ library. It relies on another preprocessor, and therefore it cannot truly be called C++.

Comment: @franzose: I'm not sure how Qt's way of handling either of those things is more "transparent" -- I think the `std::basic_string<>` template is just fine, and you don't need an external library for it. Yes, there are other things that Qt does, but it adds an awful lot of pain to your build process unless that can be extremely annoying if you're using it for something simple like receiving a URL, in comparison with traditional C or C++ libraries.

Comment: @Billy  That's true, but I don't know that it is really a valid concern.  Think of it as an extension to the language.  The syntax you use to develop Qt applications is c++ with a (very) few extra keywords added.  The development of most lare-scale applications require the inclusion of development libraries.  Qt just happens to come with an entire SDK including it's own build system.  Like it or leave it, my point was that Qt was much more than just a GUI.

Comment: @Imanol Due to time constraints I soon abandoned that project and stopped researching...

Answer (score 0):

`PyQt` and the other bindings to Qt are bindings to the core Qt library. To add bindings to your own (possibly Qt-based) classes, you'll have to use tools like SWIG or SIP (`PyQt`'s tool which may be more relevant for Qt-related classes) to generate the bindings. Alternatively, you can make a C API to your library which is easier to wrap and bind from scripting languages.

That said, you should first understand what you need Qt for at all. Are you planning a GUI or using any other capabilities Qt provides? Which?

Comment: Not GUI but work at least with strings, urls, files to retrieve and process textual data.

Comment: @franzose: the scripting languages you want to connect to usually have more convenient libraries and interfaces than Qt for this

Comment: @franzose: anyway, Qt won't help you make C++ more amenable to bindings from Python/Ruby etc.

Comment: Yes, I've understood it already. I'll use Qt Creator just as an nice IDE :) All the rest I'll do myself.